# How to use RSpec to test code with Ruby safe navigation &. operator?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'd like to write a unit test for code of this form:

```
class Foo
  def bar(obj)
    return nil unless obj&.foo
    obj.bar
  end
end
```

Here's the example test:

```
RSpec.describe Foo do
  subject { Foo.new.bar(obj) }

  context 'when obj is nil' do
    let(:obj) { nil }

    it 'does not call :foo' do
      expect(obj).to_not receive(:foo)
      subject
    end
  end
end
```

This code returns:

```
Failures:

  1) Foo when obj is nil does not call :foo
     Failure/Error: expect(obj).to_not receive(:foo)
       An expectation of `:foo` was set on `nil`. To allow expectations on `nil` and suppress this message, set `RSpec::Mocks.configuration.allow_message_expectations_on_nil` to `true`. To disallow expectations on `nil`, set `RSpec::Mocks.configuration.allow_message_expectations_on_nil` to `false`
```

By default, RSpec 3.x complains when setting an expectation on `nil`. I have a large code base so I can't modify this global setting to make testing this kind of code simpler. A global change could cause problems for other developers.

I know I could modify the code to something like `return nil unless obj.present? && obj.foo` but I'm specifically curious about handling the safe navigation operator. Lots of googling has turned up zippo on this topic.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd encourage you to test the behaviour rather than the implementation, so test that when obj is nil the result of the method call is whatever value obj.bar returns, and when not nil, the result is nil.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most clean of ways but enabling expectations on nil before the test and disabling it again afterwards would at least work. So changing the spec to

```
RSpec.describe Foo do
  subject { Foo.new.bar(obj) }

  context 'when obj is nil' do
    let(:obj) { nil }

    before do 
      RSpec::Mocks.configuration.allow_message_expectations_on_nil = true
    end

    after do 
      RSpec::Mocks.configuration.allow_message_expectations_on_nil = false
    end

    it 'does not call :foo' do
      expect(obj).to_not receive(:foo)
      subject
    end
  end
end
```

If it is a recurring pattern one could also put that before and after block inside an rspec macro (`context 'when obj is nil', nil_mock: true do`).

However, I am not sure if it is worth it as messing with those global settings has side effects which might cause some order dependent bugs that are hard to debug later on. Additionally, I would actually only test whether `foo` has been called when it is a command, meaning that it alters the system state and as such has side effects. If it is just accessing a variable, or calculating a value and as such has no side effects, I wouldn't bother testing the call at all and instead focus on testing the input and output of the method under test.

Comment: Interesting idea using the `before`/`after`blocks. I agree that this could have strange side effects though. Regarding your advice about testing the input/output of the method, I agree. However, the safety operator can (and is) used in many situations where it issues a command. Don't get too hung up on my specific example above.